# Is having a chance of 25 percent to win the same as 5 times 5 percent?

Tags: probability

I just asked this myself and liked to know if this is the case and why it is or is not.

**Option 1:** 
You have 1 time a chance of 25% to win

**Option 2:**
You have 5 times a chance 5% to win but only until you won once

Are both options the same and if not, which one is better and why is it?

Comment: If I gave you a 20 chances to win at 5%, does this mean you will definitely win?

Comment: $0.95^5=0.775>0.75$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution

Comment: @MattB Of course not! I know that but still I'd like to hear the explanation.

Comment: @almagest So for the second Option the chance is 22.5%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a one time chance with $25\%$ chance of winning, then you, obviously, will have a $25\%$ chance of winning.

However, if you have $5$ chances of winning, each with a $5\%$ chance of winning, then it is easier to calculate the probability that you will lose every time rather than directly calculate the probability that you win once. There is a $95\%$ chance of you losing, so the probability of you losing $5$ times in a row is $95\%$ times itself $5$ times. **Whenever you have independent events like this, you multiply the probability of the events happening altogether to find the probability of them all happening.**

$$95\%^5=0.95^5 \approx 0.774=77.4\%$$

Now, if that's the probability of you losing every time, then the probability of you winning is the complement of that:

$$100\%-77.4\%=22.6\%$$

Clearly, $25\%$ and $22.6\%$ are not the same chances of winning! **Your mistake was that you multiplied the number of chances by the probability, which is not valid reasoning.** It is very easy to fall into this trap, but make your best attempt to avoid it because you will almost certainly get the probability wrong if you make this mistake!

Comment: Question states ".... chance 5% to win **but only until you won once.**

Comment: It doesn't matter. The chance of you winning once is still the complement of you losing five times. I found the probability of you winning at least once and that condition does not affect that probability.

Comment: This explains everything I need to know. Thanks a lot (of course to all of you)

Answer (score 0):

Let's calculate your odds for option #$2$:

- The probability of winning after exactly $1$ attempt is $0.05$
- The probability of winning after exactly $2$ attempts is $(1-0.05)\times0.05$
- The probability of winning after exactly $3$ attempts is $(1-0.05)^{2}\times0.05$
- The probability of winning after exactly $4$ attempts is $(1-0.05)^{3}\times0.05$
- The probability of winning after exactly $5$ attempts is $(1-0.05)^{4}\times0.05$

So for option #$2$, the overall probability of winning is:

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{5}(1-0.05)^{n-1}\times0.05\approx0.22$$

For option #$1$, the probability of winning is obviously $0.25$, hence better.